# How do I access the linkedin API?

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, linkedin-api

I am trying to access linkedin API using python code. Here's the code that I am running on my windows machine:

```
from linkedin import server
import webbrowser
API_KEY = "<API_KEY>"
API_SECRET = "<API_SECRET>"
application = server.quick_api(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
```

I am executing these statements one-by-one in the console, but when I execute `server.quick_api(API_KEY, API_SECRET)`, I receive the following error:

```
>>> application = server.quick_api(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=r_basicprofile%20rw_nus%20r_network%20r_contactinfo%20w_messages%20rw_groups%20r_emailaddress%20r_fullprofile&state=0b0290ff6e51e14c5409434a6e4bf52f&redirect_uri=http%3A//localhost%3A8000/&response_type=code&client_id=<API_KEY>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2731, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-9-eb867f0fb231>", line 1, in <module>
    application = server.quick_api(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
  File "C:\Users\sony\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\linkedin\server.py", line 24, in quick_api
    _wait_for_user_to_enter_browser(app)
  File "C:\Users\sony\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\linkedin\server.py", line 38, in _wait_for_user_to_enter_browser
    httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

I get a url which I understand I am supposed to get, but what's the cause of this error?
Also, when I paste the url in the browser, it takes me to linkedin page and asks for my credentials which it never accepts *(I am sure I am entering the correct credentials)*. It always shows:

> "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

I am otherwise able to login to [linkedin](http://www.linkedin.com/) using the same credentials.

Comment: i didnt check the linkedin API yet but I know that the callback url with twitter has to be a public url not a private one like your with `http://localhost̀  . Isnt it the case here two ?

Comment: I have been able to access the API using a somewhat different method. Not really sure what's wrong with this method given that it works for other people. Here's the other method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600244/how-to-use-linkedin-api-with-python