# Login on linkedin using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm starting a small project to scrape linkedin data using selenium, the first thing I'm noticing is that the login page is not working the same way  when I use selenium.

When I load the page manually on the brower I get this response:

[image]

But when I do the same using selenium the response is different, even when the url is the same:

[image]

I a manually click on "iniciar sesion" I get redirected to the lonin page:

[image]

But the url is the same, how can I directly load proper page or trick the site so It does not detect than I'm using selenium?

This is the code I currently have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import time
import argparse
import os

#Define the argument parser to read in the URL
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-url', '--url', help='URL to the online repository of images')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
url = args['url']
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/m/login/"


# Initialize the Chrome webdriver and open the URL
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
```

EDIT:

I found that this link loads the right page directly:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=%2Fvoyager%2FloginRedirect%2Ehtml&amp;fromSignIn=true&amp;trk=uno-reg-join-sign-in
```

Comment: I think the issue is that when doing it off your regular browser Linkedin has cookies that recognize you have logged in before and redirect you to that page, but with selenium it looks like a completely new view so they redirect to the login/signup page. The easiest thing to do is to write the page with what selenium sees.

Comment: Why not just use their API: https://www.linkedin.com/developers/ ?

Comment: @SiKing I want to scrape data from the "content" search option, is it posible to do it with the API?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly!  You should probably use the API to access the data sets you are after.

https://pypi.org/project/python-linkedin-v2/

See the link below for some additional ideas of how to move this forward.

[How to use linkedin API with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600244/how-to-use-linkedin-api-with-python)

If you can't use the API, you probably shouldn't be doing this, at least not on LinkedIn.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

First I would advise to be careful about scraping LinkedIn because it goes against their policies and they have inclusively issued lawsuits on the matter.

As a purely academically answer, browser is detected by the user agent header so you would need to change that by setting the variable `"general.useragent.override"` in your Firefox profile.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

In this example the user agent is changed for Internet Explorer.

Comment: I tried adding your code but I'm getting the same result.

Regarding their policies this is for my personal use only, but as far as I know linkedin actually lose those lawsuits, I guess that's why the site is harder to scrape now.